# Android Studio 3.1 gradle build throws java.util.zip.ZipException

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.1

I'm getting this during gradle builds after the upgrade to Android Studio 3.0:

> Execution failed for task
>   ':lf-android-myproject:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug'.
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/my/package/name/SomeCustomView.class

The class in question comes from my code, it's not from a library.

It happens only with my classes that have custom attributes declared:

```
<declare-styleable name="SomeCustomView">
    <attr name="someCustomViewText" format="reference|string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

I can fix it by cleaning and then building from the console, but it pops up again eventually.

I can fix it also by renaming the class or the styleable, but I really don't want to mess with our code just to go around an AS (or gradle?) bug that can be fixed in the future probably.

Is it an Android Studio bug? Are there any workarounds?

Gradle version is: gradle-4.1-all

Android Gradle plugin version is: 3.0.1

Comment: How did you access that class? Is it a library? Did you using a library which is depend on the view then you use the library on your main project?

Comment: It's not a library class, it's my class. But my project consists of several android libraries and this class is from one of them.

Comment: I once experience this when I'm reusing the same attribute from existing library.

Comment: I think it's connected somehow to the fact that declare-styleable from declaration of custom attributes has the same name as the name of my custom view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by deleting Android Studio files from the project and re-importing the project.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be found for different reason. However, Here is a way to fix Gradle build error: “java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry”

If you’ve updated some libraries in your android project and then encountered the following error while assembling it (or something similar):
[image]

The reason is that some libraries have similar dependencies, therefore the compiler can not choose the appropriate one.

According to the logs, the problem in the duplicated class
org/intellij/lang/annotations/Identifier.class
To find this class usages, you should filter the detailed gradle log:
[image]

Fix it!
Remove one of the dependencies:
[image]

Follow this for your case and I guess you will find your solution.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but in my case duplication is in my code, not in library code

Comment: oh, So the problem is fixed right? And this guideline help you somehow even some understanding i guess.

Comment: No, it's not fixed :(